# How to display the last two pages of a pagination range using v-pagination

Tags: pagination, vuejs3, vue-component, storybook, vuetifyjs3

I am a beginner to vue.js and Vuetify.

I want to display the last two pages of a pagination range using v-pagination.

In vuetify 3 there is only one last page range is showing. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/chUlX.png)

But I want to display the last two page range like this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyuyA.png)

It's that possible to customize like that?

Comment: Looking at the implementation of VPagination, particularly [the way the range is build](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VPagination/VPagination.tsx#L190-L215) with hard-coded position of the ellipsis, I am gonna say it is not possible at the moment.